# Use CalibratedClassifierCV to calibrator my own classifier (not a sklearn classifier)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, calibration

Say for example I have a classifier which uses the cosine-similarity as a `predict_proba` measure e.g

```py
class Classifier:
    def fit(self,X,y):
       # X is a sparse matrix
       self.X = X
       self.y = y
   
    def predict_proba(self, X):
       similarity = X@self.X.T
       proba = transform_similarity_to_correct_predict_proba_format(similarity)
       return proba #same format as sklearn.<model>.predict_proba
```

and I want to calibrate that classifier.

I could just train an Isotonic regression, but since I have multiple targets, sklearn handles this nicely by calibrate within each different target, thus I would like to avoid doing that my self.

Is there a way that I can use `CalibratedClassifierCV` with my own class without having to inherit it from sklearns base-classifier? Can't we, in some way, just parse `(X_proba, y)` to `CalibratedClassifierCV` and then make it do it that way?

Answer (score 0):

Unless `cv="prefit"`, `CalibratedClassifierCV` *clones* the base estimator across cross-validation folds before fitting/predicting/training the calibrator:  https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7f9bad99d6e0a3e8ddf92a7e5561245224dab102/sklearn/calibration.py#L430-L443

Cloning requires `get_params` and `set_params`, which come automatically through inheriting from `BaseEstimator`, but you can provide them manually if you want.

If you can use `"prefit"`, then it's possible that you don't need `BaseEstimator` inheritance for everything to work out.  A quick scan of the source code and I mostly see things like standard attributes (`classes_`) and methods `predict_proba`.  I haven't done a thorough look through the code though, nor have I tested this (which would probably be faster if you're interested).